# GDB, examine pointer to pointer

Tags: c, gdb

Ok, so I'm trying to learn gdb. I know most of the basics but I have not been able to figure out how to examine a pointer to a pointer in a oneliner. It might be possible by defining a macro/command but I haven't been able to do so.

This question began when learning the cdecl calling convention where $esp contained a pointer to a string, passed as an argument to a function. In order to get this out I had to do the following:

```
gdb$ x $esp+0x08
0xbffff6a4: 0x980eb192
gdb$ x/s 0x980eb192
0x980eb192:  "Hello world"
```

So, the question is. Can this be done in an easier way? Cutting and pasting just feels too slow.

Appreciate any hints/ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(gdb) x/s *(char**)($esp+8)` might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse results of `print` in subsequent expressions:

```
(gdb) p *(void **)($esp + 4)
$4 = (void *) 0x80aec48
(gdb) x/s $4
0x80aec48:   "alabala"
```